# TimeSpinner Check If Undefined Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, spinner, jquery-ui-spinner

Currently I have a an input text field that may or may not have a timespinner tied to that particular element. In some cases, I need to remove the timespinner functionality altogether (as opposed to disabling it), to display it properly on the page.

Currently, I have code to check if the timespinner exists on the element as follows:

```
if ($("#ElementOfInterest").timespinner !== undefined){
    $("#ElementOfInterest").timespinner("destroy");
}
```

**This works fine when the page is first loaded**, however, this throws the following exception:

> cannot call methods on timespinner prior to initialization; attempted
>   to call method 'destroy'

For some reason, the check for `undefined` passes and tries to a timespinner on the element that doesn't exist.

So the only way for my UI to run properly at the moment is to wrap it in a `try/catch` block like this:

```
if ($("#ElementOfInterest").timespinner !== undefined) {
    try {
        $("#ElementOfInterest").timespinner("destroy");
    } catch (error) {
    }
}
```

This works, but it is rather sloppy. I would rather have the check be successful and remove the `try/catch` block from the code.

Am I missing some special check or something? What's going on here?

**Update**

I tried the following code suggested by @GlenSwift:

```
if (typeof $("#ElementOfInterest").spinner("instance") !== 'undefined') {
    $("#ElementOfInterest").timespinner("destroy");
}
```

This however, gave me this exception:

> cannot call methods on spinner prior to initialization; attempted to
>   call method 'instance'

I also tried `timespinner("instance")` but I simply got back:

> undefined is not a method

So it looks like checking for an instance of a timespinner was not implemented.

Comment: "this throws an exception". Pls, provide error message?

Comment: Added the exception that is being thrown in my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `$("#ElementOfInterest").timespinner !== undefined` just checks if `$().timespinner` is defined, which it will be as long as the plugin is loaded. How about checking if the element has the class the the spinner adds.  `if ($("#ElementOfInterest").hasClass('ui-spinner-input'))`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if (typeof $( "#ElementOfInterest" ).spinner( "instance" ) !== 'undefined') {
    $("#ElementOfInterest").timespinner("destroy");
}
```

ref: http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/#method-instance

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. I believe I tried this before without any decent results. I updated my question with the exception I received.

Comment: Pls, check if jquery and jquery ui is loaded at the moment of code execution